# Having children of an element animate separately but in order

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have three children div elements in a parent div

```
<div id="fatherDiv">
    //First Div
    <div class="childrenDiv"></div>
    //Second Div
    <div class="childrenDiv"></div>
    //Third Div
    <div class="childrenDiv"></div>
</div>
```

I'm attempting to get each child to animate in the order they are in through jQuery. So the first div will animate on it's own, then the second will move once the first is done, and then  finally the third after the second is done. How would I be able to do that?

---

**Edit**

Sorry, to clarify, when I say animate, I mean .animate(); In this example, I guess we can have it moves downwards, say, 10 pixels.

Comment: What do you mean by animate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/skHHP/)</kbd>

This should do the job.

```
function anim($child) {
    //look for the next sibling
    var $next = $child.next('.childrenDiv');
    $child.animate({
        'top':'+=10px'
    }, function() {
        //if there was a next child, then animate it
        if ($next.length > 0)
            anim($next);
    });
}

//start the animation with the first .childrenDiv child of #fatherDiv
anim($('#fatherDiv .childrenDiv:first-child'));
```

We just declare a little method called `anim` that uses a recurring callback to select the next `.childrenDiv` if one is available and animates it. We call it using the first child of `#fatherDiv`.

This is just basic recursion, the base case being if there is no next sibling to animate.

Comment: Yes, one needs to finish before the next one starts.

Comment: Great! If you don't mind @Alex Morrise, would you mind explaining why you did what you did? I'm trying to fully comprehend the thought process and learn from this :)

Comment: I just edited my answer with a little more explanation. Is there a specific part you'd like me to elaborate on?

Comment: Actually no, this is perfect man. Very awesome man. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 1):

From the [jQuery UI .animate() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#animate-properties-duration-easing-complete)

Just use callbacks via the complete function to perform the animations in whatever order you like.

**Complete Function**

> If supplied, the complete callback function is fired once the
>   animation is complete. This can be useful for stringing different
>   animations together in sequence. The callback is not sent any
>   arguments, but this is set to the DOM element being animated. If
>   multiple elements are animated, the callback is executed once per
>   matched element, not once for the animation as a whole.